# Why numbers are sometimes treated as characters in R?

Tags: r

I have created a panel data set by compiling data from several sources. But why the variables, i.e. `local_aus`, `hyv_aus`, and `hyv_aman` are being considered as characters instead of numbers? I used: 
`mutate(local_aus = as.numeric(local_aus)`, `hyv_aus = as.numeric(hyv_aus)`,`hyv_aman = as.numeric(hyv_aman))`

However, R shows,  `warning messages: NAs introduced by coercion`. But why are those numeric values being considered as charcaters?

```
Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':   856 obs. of  24 variables:
 $ district             : num  11704 10408 11921 12007 11313 ...
 $ year                 : num  1970 1970 1970 1970 1970 1970 1970 1970 1970 1970 ...
 $ local_aus            : chr  "178145" "94390" "119375" "56375" ...
 $ hyv_aus              : chr  "3010" "850" "2095" "3785" ...
 $ broadcast_aman       : num  70325 9435 33340 1495 316580 ...
 $ local_transplant_aman: num  673060 270550 282655 35825 188655 ...
 $ hyv_aman             : chr  "3185" "920" "3080" "820" ...
 $ local_boro           : num  6450 12050 41430 14450 45970 ...
 $ hyv_boro             : num  67930 10630 121340 15640 116500 ...
 $ danger_days_aus      : num  0 0 142 4 108 434 5 36 33 1 ...
 $ benefit_days_aus     : num  0 0 9 0 21 110 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ danger_days_aman     : num  0 0 32 0 43 218 0 0 29 2 ...
 $ benefit_days_aman    : num  0 0 89 0 110 426 3 52 53 2 ...
 $ danger_days_boro     : num  0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ benefit_days_boro    : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ abovemax_aus         : num  2 25 1 37 4 18 29 19 45 42 ...
 $ belowmin_aus         : num  1 1 2 4 2 0 3 3 2 0 ...
 $ abovemax_aman        : num  0 0 0 0 1 0 2 1 1 6 ...
 $ belowmin_aman        : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ abovemax_boro        : num  2 7 0 10 1 8 4 7 5 12 ...
 $ belowmin_boro        : num  116 123 107 92 76 115 138 125 124 89 ...
 $ rain_aus             : num  5969 1088 6902 5637 3831 ...
 $ rain_aman            : num  5477 650 5806 2291 2900 ...
 $ rain_boro            : num  601.6 38.1 1067.3 381 387.4 ...
```

Comment: Most likely there are some strings somewhere in the column. Often this is due to something besides NA being used for missing.

Comment: Maybe just try `hyv_aus[is.na(as.numeric(hyv_aus))]` to see how thous values which produce `NA`s look like in a wild? Probably it's better to use `head` above, if your dataset is big.

Comment: It's likely because they were originally `factor`s. You need `as.numeric(as.character(........))` most likely. A `dput` would help.

Answer (score 0):

As the others have mentioned, you most likely have some irregular `NA`s among your numeric values. It's also possible that you've imported your CSV using the wrong decimal format. Take a look at rows 3-5 in the `local_aus` column. The values `-`, `563,75`, and `none` would all cause R to coerce the column into class "character":

```r
# A tibble: 5 x 2
   year local_aus
  <int> <chr>    
1  1970 178145   
2  1970 94390    
3  1970 -        
4  1970 563,75   
5  1970 none
```

If you run `as.numeric(df$local_aus)` you'll get the same warning you describe above. You can use regular expressions to find the problematic values (assuming the values are supposed to be integers):

```r
> df$local_aus[!grepl("^\\d+$", df$local_aus)]
[1] "-"      "563,75" "none"
```

It's best to deal with these issues in your call to `read.*` or `readr::read_*`. Here are two examples that will import the above example dataframe correctly:

```r
# using base R
df <- read.table("example.txt",
                 header = T,
                 stringsAsFactors = F,
                 dec = ",",
                 na.strings = c("-", "none")
                 )

# using readr library
df <- readr::read_table("example.txt",
                        locale = locale(decimal_mark = ","),
                        na = c("-", "none")
                        )

#### OUTPUT ####

df

# A tibble: 5 x 2
   year local_aus
  <dbl>     <dbl>
1  1970   178145 
2  1970    94390 
3  1970       NA 
4  1970      564.
5  1970       NA
```